# How to convert .img file extension in ios using objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsdata, xcode9

I am getting a image file with extension .img from a url . So i am converting it to the NSData and converting back to the UIImage file. 
Conversion to NSData is successful but UIImage is returning nil. 
How to work with the .img extension.

This is the URL:
http://example.com:8080/track/patch/FAN_2.1.0.1.IMG

```
   -(void)downloadImgFromURL:(NSString *)urlString{
    NSString *strImgURLAsString = urlString;
    // [strImgURLAsString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImgURLAsString];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:imgURL] queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        if (!connectionError) {

            UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data ];
            NSLog(@"Image:%@",img);

//            self.addFanImage.image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data ];
            // pass the img to your imageview
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",connectionError);
        }
    }];
}
```

Please do tell where i am getting it wrong?

Comment: That's a strange objective.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting a image file with extension .img from a url

No, you're not.

An `.img` file is *not* an image (a picture). It is a "disk image" which is a very different thing (an executable file, roughly speaking).

If your goal is merely to transfer the file to local storage, use URLConnection and do a [download task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloadtask). But I can't imagine what you think you're going to *do* with such a file once you have downloaded it.

Comment: thanks for the information. But how to handle this? Is there some other way to handle this?

Comment: That doesn't change anything about my answer. The notion that you're going to deal with this as a UIImage is simply insane. The notion that you're going to _anything_ with it is incomprehensible; I can't imagine what you are downloading it for in the first place.

Comment: ok.. I accept. But how to handle with the URL from where it is showing .img extension

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with it. What do you want to do with the .img file?

Comment: @Terje i just want to save locally that .IMG file. Please do help

Comment: Then just do a download task. Done. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiondownloadtask

Comment: But Matt's question remains. A .img file is a *disk image*. Why would you possibly want to download a disk image onto an iOS device? You won't be able to do anything with it locally.